# how to disable drop down when checkbox is unchecked in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am new to angular js.
I want to know how to disable drop down when checkbox is unchecked in angular js.this is the code i have been trying...

Click me:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
<div>
<div class="check-element animate-hide" ng-show="checked">

 <select ng-model="myDropDown">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By having `checked` defined as your checkbox's model you can just that to control whether the select (drop down) is disabled using that variable on your controller's scope.

```
<select ng-model="myDropDown" ng-disabled="!checked">
```

make sure you use the negation of checked since you want it to be disabled when the checkbox is not checked.

[PLNKR example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uIIKJvJcE09n7vL3ryGQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<select ng-model="myDropDown" ng-disabled="!checked">
```

Use `ng-disabled` conditionally on if the `ng-model` for your checkbox is `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a real quick example. Below I have a select box. You can use ng-disabled="EXPRESSION" to dynamically disable stuff.

```
  <select ng-model="dropdown" ng-options="item.name for item in dropdown" ng-disabled="!checked">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
```

Just set the expression to check the variable that is true/false on your checkbox. When it is false (unchecked) your dropdown will be disabled